# Intel Wireless 7265 doesn't connect after change another network

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, network-manager, intel-wireless

Grettings!

I have Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 with kernel 4.10.0-21-generic fresh installed.

When I connect the first time to a wireless network works perfectly. However when I try to change to another network doesn't connect and dmseg displayed this error:

```
aborting authentication with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: No association and the time event is over already
```

My lsmod:

```
iwlwifi               229376  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              602112  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
```

I did already try set power manager off, disable ipv6, edit nsswitch.conf, killall wpa_supplicant, set REGDOMAIN, set 'options iwlwifi swcrypto=1 11n_disable=8' into iwlwifi.conf.

Thanks for advanced

Comment: I have the same problem (same log message).  It only happens when I connect to an ac network, not when I connect to a gn network.

Comment: I did try debian 8 and every works well. I believe the problem it's the iwlwifi driver